# Cocos 2d Iphone v3 Sprite from spritesheet and shader

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, shader, sprite

Search the stackoverflow and Google returned no results.

```
 [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"sun.plist"];
 CCSprite* sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"8.jpg" ];
 sprite.position = ccp(self.contentSize.width/2 + 300, self.contentSize.height/2);
 [self addChild: sprite];
```

The display shows the selected sprite from plist

but if I apply a shader program, the sprites overlap

What is the solution?
without shader:
[image]

overlap:

[image]

thx

---UPDT 05.05.2014

```
@interface gSprite : CCSprite
...
- (void) draw;
@end

- (void) draw{
....
            _shaderProgram = [[CCShaderCache sharedShaderCache] programForKey:@"LightingBlurShader"];
            [_shaderProgram  use];
            [_shaderProgram setUniformsForBuiltins];

            glUniform1i([[Engine sharedEngine] lightCount], activeLighCount);
            glUniform2fv([[Engine sharedEngine] lightPositionUniformLocation], activeLighCount, arrayLigthPos);
            glUniform1fv([[Engine sharedEngine] lightFalloffUniformLocation],activeLighCount, arrayLightFalloff);
            glUniform1fv([[Engine sharedEngine] lightIntensityUniformLocation], activeLighCount, arrayLightIntensity);
....

[super draw];

} //draw
```

Comment: I think the links of your images don't work, you can always add these images directly onto the question.

Comment: to link images need 10 reputation post, but i novice member  ) I reloaded pic to another site

Comment: I've added the images for you.

Comment: Could you post also the code where you apply the shader?

Comment: I updated the start post. Maybe the problem is that I need to pass the shader coordinates of the current frame of the animation?